# call recorder failed in android

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am trying the following code :

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
           recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
           recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
           recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
           recorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/sound123.mp4");//(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
           recorder.prepare();

           recorder.start();
```

my app is crashing on recorder.start(); I have changed AudioSource.VOICE_CALL to AudioSource..MIC as suggested in stackoverflow but its still crashing on start.

I have given following permissions in manifest :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" ></uses-permission>      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Its giving me following exception:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your setOutputFile is the issue. Try changing this line:

```
recorder.setOutputFile("/mnt/sdcard/sound123.mp4");//(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
```

To

```
recorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/sound123.3gp"
```

Also realize that you are setting the output format as 3gp and your file has extension .mp4

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/sound123.mp4";
        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }
        mRrecorder=new MediaRecorder();

        mRrecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRrecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mRrecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRrecorder.setOutputFile(path);
        mRrecorder.prepare();
        mRrecorder.start();
```

Comment: file is getting saved with size of 0 bytes... so i think thats not a problem

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem while trying to do voice recording. My recorder would work once, but second time it would crash the app. I suspected re-innit the recorder obj was the problem but testing didn't prove that.

in the end i added :

```
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
recorder = null;
```

The release and null lines did the trick. no more crashing.
Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer, but I try to answer. Android's official site [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) that MediaRecorder does not work on the emulator. So, don't work on the emulator to use MediaRecorder.